# Paragraph margin not expaning containing div

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have used [jquery mobile framework](http://jquerymobile.com/) to build the following about web page:

http://manchestergardeningservices.co.uk/mob/about.php

Please look at the tinted paragraph below the `<h1>` element.

I am concerned that the `<p>` element inside of the `<div>` element with a class of "lime_tint" is not expanding this `<div>` that is acting as it's container. The `<p>` element has some default top and bottom margin that should surely push out the top and bottom of the containing  element.

For example in Google Chrome when the paragraph element is inspected I can see the following styling. My understanding is that the -webkit-margin-before and -webkit-margin-after set at 1em should widen the containing div element so that there is extra green space above and below the paragraph element. Why is this not the case.

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what those webkit attributes should be doing. I would just add some padding to the DIV in order to expand it.

Comment: I will be doing this and removing the margin from the <p> elements, however it is a concern that the top and bottom margin on the <p> elements in Firefox and Chrome etc is not expanding the containing <div>

Comment: Are you using a css rest stylesheet on your page? If so I believe that it will overide those webkit rules.

Comment: I will give that a go thanks, it may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add some padding to the .lime_tint  div e.g.

```
.lime_tint {padding:10px;}
```

This will push the `<p>` tag 10px "in" form all sides of the div and the div will expand accordingly.